# alternate option for getElementById in JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I  have a MVC app.

I have written JS code below in the "Create" view. The code below code works perfectly in Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox; but it's not working in IE 8.

```
$('#PaymentType').change(function(){            
            var ptype=document.getElementById("PaymentType").value;        
        });
```

So I changed it to the code below and it works... on IE 8 as well

```
$('#PaymentType').change(function(){            
             var ptype = $(this).val();        
        });
```

Now, the problem is that I am not going to use `getElementById` anymore...

What if I want to get the values from another control? Which alternate option is there available to `getElementById`?

Comment: are you clear about what '#PaymentType' does?

Comment: ya, Its a drop down list, and after chnaging its value I want get that value and want to store in ptype

Answer (score 2):

You just use `$('#otherId').val()` to get the value.

Also on a side note in your second code example you could've just used `var ptype = this.value;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you don't need to use `document.getElementById` anymore.

I would be interested to know why it doesn't work though, it looks like it should.

Comment: IE8 is picky about select field values.